# jQuery UI Droppable Accept drops from only certain classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

I have 3 div elements all with class `abs` and only one of them has and additional class `outside` as you see below. All elements are draggable and droppable (using jquery ui).

The problem is I do not want the div with class `outside` to be dropped into other `abs` divs or to accept any `abs`divs to be dropped into it. I only want to be able to drop `abs` into other `abs` without `outside` existing in either. I tried the following but i'm still able to drag the `outside` div into other `abs` divs. I do not want that. Can you help guide me into the proper way to prevent this from happening.

**Check jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/PWh2L/**

```
<div class="abs"></div>
<div class="abs outside"></div>
<div class="abs"></div>

$('.abs').draggable();
$('.abs:not(.outside)').droppable({
    accept: '.abs',
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    greedy: true
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you just need to drop `'.abs:not(.outside)'` in to the accept option like so:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PWh2L/1/)**

```
$('.abs').draggable();
$('.abs:not(.outside)').droppable({
    accept: '.abs:not(.outside)', // Important bit
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    greedy: true,
    drop: function () {
        alert('drop');
    }
});
```

Or perhaps this is more what you're after:

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/PWh2L/2/)**

```
$('.abs').draggable();
$('.abs').droppable({ // Change here
    accept: '.abs:not(.outside)', // and here
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    greedy: true,
    drop: function () {
        alert('drop');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks i didn't know we had this flexibility in the accept option.